# Is it discourteous to suggest a different answer be accepted?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Occasionally an answer could solve (or help solve) an asker's problem - and hence be accepted - but may not be beneficial to the community.

In cases where the answer is simply too specific, this can be harmless (and often another responder will leave a more generalisable answer). But occasionally an accepted answer may actually be a bad idea for many users (even though it was helpful to the asker of the question).

A fairly strident example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946435/devise-why-doesnt-my-logout-link-work) - note the comments on the accepted answer (basically it introduces a security vulnerability).

In cases as pronounced as this, is it inappropriate or discourteous to drop a comment on the question suggesting another answer be accepted? Or is it expected that readers should always view several answers to minimise the risk of going by sub optimal information?

Comment: Being accepted doesn't mean that is the right answer, it is the answer most helpful to the asker. Downvote it into oblivion if you feel it is plain wrong, or worse a threat. You would be fairly stupid to take code from an answer with a score of -10 wouldn't you?

Comment: @Luuklag thanks for the link to the question mine was a dup of. I can’t help but notice the irony that the accepted answer is not the most upvoted hehe

Comment: You would have to thank @Tinkeringbell for that Steve.